# Build Validation Pipeline Causes Branch to be Locked Down

Tags: azure-devops

I have a simple Azure DevOps Pipeline

```yaml
trigger:
- dev
- features/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'devops-nuget-guid'
```

That is set up as the build validation pipeline for the dev branch and any "features" branches

[image: Build Validation Setup]

The problem is that when a developer first pushes a branch and the pipeline runs, it sets the branch security to prevent them from being allowed to push any further commits to the branch (this did not occur prior to having the build validation pipeline enabled and goes away by disabling it). This causes issues when there are changes that need to be made from a code review (or even when working on a larger story over a couple of days and wanting to save work to the repo). I'm able to go in after the branch is created and manually change branch security to allow the developer to push up further changes, but that's a pain. It's not possible to set branch security (that I found in the UI) on "features" and have that apply to any branch created under there (i.e. features/123-dv-BranchDescription). Below is the git workflow / error:

```bash
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 19, done.
Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Delta compression using up to 20 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 8.16 KiB | 522.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Analyzing objects... (13/13) (602 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (88 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (58 ms)
To ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/Company/Project/Repo
 ! [remote rejected] features/123-dv-BranchDescription -> features/123-dv-BranchDescription (TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch.)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/Company/Project/Repo'
```

How can I either:

- Stop the build validation pipeline from altering branch security to lock out developers
- Set branch security automatically on features branches to allow developers to push
- Something else? I just need it to work and open to any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use branch policies for feature branches? CI - yes, that`s a correct decision. But build validations for the features folder should be disabled because that is a sandbox for the developers. I suggest to remove all policies from the features level... or you have some project requirements for that part?

[image]

`the pipeline runs and causes the branch security to change` - it is not a pipeline job to change branch policies. Your yaml trigger describes CI part and not the validation checks. Check the documentation:

- [CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)
- [PR triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers)

Comment: The pipeline is running on feature branches to provide automated quality gates prior to a PR being approved and merged into the dev branch. The PR review process includes the reviewer pulling the branch, ensuring it builds, testing the functionality, and running unit tests... but, due to human error, sometimes dev ends up broken due to a failure to follow the process correctly every time. The plan is for the pipeline to have more quality gates in the future like static code analysis and unit test coverage. A PR cannot be approved and merged into the dev branch unless the pipeline succeeds.

Comment: The problem is, when the build validation pipeline runs, it is altering the branch security to prevent further pushes to the branch. That prevents the developer from being able to push up changes to the branch that come out of the code review... or even to fix their code if the pipeline fails (thus identifying build errors they have to fix). Providing quality gates is the whole point to a build validation pipeline but it altering the branch security seems to be a bug.